# How do I retrieve a list of users from Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to create an online user directory and pull the information directly from Active Directory. So after hours of searching I came up with this solution(which is not much of a solution). When I run my program all it does is spin like it wants to do something but after all of the spinning it gives me a blank white page.

```
protected void btnClick_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dom = txtDomainName.Text;

    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dom);
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry);
    mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=user)");
    Console.WriteLine("Listing of users in the Active Directory");
    Console.WriteLine("========================================");


    foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
    {
        try
        {
            System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry();
            Console.WriteLine("Display Name  : " + de.Properties["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Email         : " + de.Properties["Mail"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Title         : " + de.Properties["Title"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("User Name     : " + de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("First Name    : " + de.Properties["GivenName"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name     : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Initials      : " + de.Properties["Initials"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Company       : " + de.Properties["Company"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Department    : " + de.Properties["Department"].Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Telephone No. : " + de.Properties["TelephoneNumber"].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        Console.WriteLine("===========    End of user   =============");

    }
    Console.WriteLine("===========    End of Listing   =============");
}
```

Please note that I know little to nothing about active directory, only that it can be use to store Employee Information and create and manage user groups. I have used C# and LDAP to create login pages that requires and verifies username and password from ID to pass authentication.

***Edited***
The application posted requires the user to put in their domain. After I enter the domain name it should list all users or something, it just spins and gives me a white page of nothing

Comment: Are you monitoring the console in the VS debug window then? The "click" suggests this is a form of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
Console.WriteLine(
```

try

```
Response.Write(string.Format(
```

This will give you a print out and that should fix your blank page issue.

Comment: That gave me a print out! its jumbled but its something!

Comment: Oops, I missed the obvious!

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams You'll need to add HTML formatting in there to get the right output.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in a console based application. I used the Directory.Services.AccountManagement class to achieve this. In my example, I am just listing the names.

```
private static string SearchUsers(UserPrincipal parUserPrincipal)
{

    PrincipalSearcher insPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher {QueryFilter = parUserPrincipal};

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = insPrincipalSearcher.FindAll();
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (UserPrincipal p in results)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("SamAccountName:{0}\t DisplayName:{1}\tUserPrincipal:{2}\tDescription:{3}\tEmail:{4}\tTel:{5}\n", p.SamAccountName, p.DisplayName, p.UserPrincipalName, p.Description, p.EmailAddress, p.VoiceTelephoneNumber);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}


public static string SetPrincipal()
{
    // **Make sure you set the correct domain name** 
    var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myCompany");
    UserPrincipal insUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(pc) {Name = "*"};
    return SearchUsers(insUserPrincipal);
}
```

Comment: I tried using `ContextType.Domain` earlier and VS started to complain saying it was not defined. What is that for? also please keep in mind I am using web forms

Comment: This code is a slight variation on the code that we're using in our INTRANET ASP .nET application.